# My php application with Xampp into a single exe or msi installer?

Tags: php, xampp

Xampp is a great product for newbie like us, it is very easy to install and configure. Today I am thinking of rolling up my php applications which I have it inside htdocs folder with the xampp installer. I know that Xampp has a zip package version too. And what I need to know now is that: is it possible and how to include my php application inside the xampp installer or exe for distribution? An example of what I want to achieve is timetracks (it has its own server and all the applications in one installer). Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You could just create your own installer too and just make sure that the correct files and services (assuming Windows) are setup by your installer.

Answer (score 2):

You Should look into using server2go http://www.server2go-web.de/ i have used various times to package my PHP apps.